# vmplayer 5: can't create VM from vmdk

Tags: 12.10, vmware

Yesterday I installed VMware player 5.0.2 from bundle file on a ubuntu 12.10 machine.
Then I created a VM containing WinXP Professional, this too went well.

But when I looked for creating a new VM starting from the previous one, I can't find any option on vmplayer library that let me do it.

No custom installation, no option to choose a vmdk to start from, as I read on some docs on internet.

My copy of vmplayer seems to not offer these functions.

I even tried to reinstall everything, running vm-installer -u vmplayer and then deleting the .vmware folder on home dirs.

But after reinstall, something seems to be still persistent : at first run it automatically position the library on the folder where VM are saved.

My question is : Can I use vmplayer 5 to create VMs starting from a previous vmdk ?
If yes, why this option is not available ?

Comment: I just add this info : at very first run of vmplayer I actually SAW both the "custom" and the "select vmdk" options while I was creating the first VM.

Then these two "disappeared"...

Answer (score 0):

VMware player does not allow you to create and edit virtual machines in the generic "player".  That's what Workstation is for.

Alternately, use VirtualBox

Comment: So the options that I saw at first start were there just "temporarily" ?

Comment: It is probably "remembering" that a vmdk file is already registered to a particular VM and not letting you use the same vmdk file for multiple VMs.

Comment: Ok, I think I'll have to switch to VirtualBox.

Can I install it without removing vmware for the moment ?